# PHP getenv HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR contain alphabet

Tags: php, ip

```
$ipaddress = '';
        if ( getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP') ) {
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        } else if( getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR') ) {
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
            $ipaddress = explode(",", $ipaddress);
            $ipaddress = $ipaddress[0];
        } else if( getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED') ) {
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
        } else if( getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR') ) {
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
        } else if( getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED') ) {
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
        } else if( getenv('REMOTE_ADDR') ) {
            $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        } else {
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
        }
        return ip2long($ipaddress);


http_client_ip - null
http_x_forwarded_for - 2604:2000:6147:df00:25ee:04a4:ea44:6947, 162.158.62.236
http_x_forwarded - null
http_forwarded_for - null
http_forwarded - null
remote_addr 112.121.183.210
```

Hi, I'm new in ip and not sure how to get real ip address.

1. I dont know why `http_x_forwarded_for` return 2 ip?
2. why `http_x_forwarded_for` 1st one contain alphabet?
3. why `http_client_ip, http_x_forwarded, http_forwarded_for, http_forwarded` are null?
4. why `remote_addr` is different from `http_x_forwarded_for`?

which one is the right ip address

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with proxies, those proxies may add X-Forwarded-For headers whenever one forwards the request. For example:

```
client -> proxy -> proxy -> server
```

Here there are two proxies involved, perhaps one on the client's premises and one at your server's data centre, or both at the client, or both at your data centre, or whatever other combination you come across.

Your server (PHP) will then see the remote IP as being the closest proxy. That's where it gets the "physical" connection from.

To be nice both proxies added the address where *they* got the request from to the HTTP headers. The "alphabetic" address is an [IPv6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6).

You should only trust any of those headers if you know who sets them. The only guaranteed proven address is the `REMOTE_ADDR`, because that's the actual connection. The others are mere HTTP headers which anyone could set, including the client itself. Unless you know you have a proxy at your data centre and you know what header it sets exactly, you should disregard them.

Comment: my server has use cdn by the way

Comment: Well then it's the CDN's proxy.

Comment: so I should only use remote_addr?

Comment: That'll always be the CDN's proxy, which is not very useful. Investigate what exact headers your CDN sets and verify that you can depend on that; then you can use that information too.

Comment: I try remote_addr & https://www.whatismyip.com/ are different, whatismyip shows HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR one

Comment: how to echo headers CDN sets? I use print_r($_SERVER); but I coulndn't find it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146271/discussion-between-benjamin-w-and-deceze).